# RMongo: How do you switch to another database?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongo

I have a mongodb like this:

```
# works
mongo -u user -p pass --authenticationDatabase "admin" --port 27018
# switch to test
use test

# does not work
mongo -u user -p pass --authenticationDatabase "test" --port 27018
```

I am using `RMongo` to connect to mongodb:

```
mg1 <- mongoDbConnect(dbName = 'admin', host = 'localhost', port = '27018')
auth <- dbAuthenticate(rmongo.object = mg1, username = 'user', password = 'pass')
```

I want to switch to another database `test` but I don't know how to do it in `RMongo`. How do you switch to another database using `RMongo`?

Thanks!